# How to increment a variable in case function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to increment an local variable in SQL Server inside a CASE WHEN statement.

I am attempting to identify a Group ID in my table when a error. I am currently using CASE WHEN & Declare as in the following statement.

My code:

```
Declare @GroupID INT = 1;
SELECT a.CPUT AS Tim
      ,a.USNA AS wayq
      ,a.WE AS Pl
      ,a.MA AS Mau
      ,b.MAK AS Material_Desc
      ,a.BW AS Movement_type
      ,c.BTE AS Movement_Type_Text
      ,lag(a.BW) over (order by a.MB ,a.ZE) as Prev_Movement_type
      ,@GroupID  = @GroupID + CAST(
                    CASE
        WHEN (a.BW = '13' AND (lag(a.BW) over (order by a.MB ,a.ZE) = '14'))
        THEN (@GroupID + 1)
        WHEN (a.BW = '13' AND (lag(a.BW) over (order by a.MB ,a.ZE) = '15'))
        THEN (@GroupID + 1)
        WHEN (a.BW = '16' AND (lag(a.BW) over (order by a.MB ,a.ZE) = '14'))
        THEN (@GroupID + 1)
        WHEN (a.BW = '16' AND (lag(a.BW) over (order by a.MB ,a.ZE) = '15'))
        THEN (@GroupID + 1)
                ELSE @GroupID
          END AS BIT) as GroupID

  FROM Database_Table3 a 
  LEFT JOIN Database_Table4 b ON (a.MA = b.MA)
  LEFT JOIN Database_Table5 c ON (a.BW = c.BW)

  WHERE a.BW IN ('13', '14', '15', '16')
  ORDER BY a.MB ,a.ZE
```

I want the following result:

[image]

Error messages in SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

I am looking for a solution to my problem.

Comment: First lesson, `CASE WHEN statement`, `CASE function` is in fact a `CASE expression` - its important to know because expressions do something very different to statements which are very different to functions.

Comment: I have no idea what you query is trying to do, please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and emphasis in *minimal*.

Comment: And many of us won't even look at images because: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You can't use variables like that, but it looks like you want to generate a grouping field which is incremented when previous value changes. This problem is called gaps and islands and you will find a lot of questions on the thema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you could modify the CASE expression to just yield a 0 or 1 and then calculate a running sum by wrapping wrap it up in a windowed SUM() function.

It looks like you could also simplify your `CASE` condition by using the `IN (...)` operator.

The combination would be something like `SUM(CASE WHEN a.BW IN ('13', '16') AND lag(a.BW) over (order by a.MB ,a.ZE) IN ('14', '15') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY a.MB, a.ZE) + 1 AS GroupId`

The problem is that (I am pretty sure) you cannot nest window functions (`LAG()` and `SUM()`) in the same single-level query. However, you *can* split the logic up into a nested select and an outer select, each with a window function.

Try something like:

```
SELECT
    s.Tim
    ,s.wayq
    ,s.Pl
    ,s.Mau
    ,s.Material_Desc
    ,s.Movement_type
    ,s.Movement_Type_Text
    ,s.Prev_Movement_type
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN s.Movement_type IN ('13', '16')
              AND s.Prev_Movement_type IN ('14', '15')
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
         OVER(ORDER BY s.MB, s.ZE) + 1 AS GroupID
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.CPUT AS Tim
        ,a.USNA AS wayq
        ,a.WE AS Pl
        ,a.MA AS Mau
        ,b.MAK AS Material_Desc
        ,a.BW AS Movement_type
        ,c.BTE AS Movement_Type_Text
        ,lag(a.BW) over (order by a.MB ,a.ZE) as Prev_Movement_type
        ,a.MB
        ,a.ZE
    FROM Database_Table3 a 
    LEFT JOIN Database_Table4 b ON (a.MA = b.MA)
    LEFT JOIN Database_Table5 c ON (a.BW = c.BW)
    WHERE a.BW IN ('13', '14', '15', '16')
) s
ORDER BY s.MB, s.ZE
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cwdqGeRN) for a demo.

Comment: Your code is Excellent. Very thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, the problem with your code is not the `CASE` expression, but rather the use of assigning a value to a variable in a `SELECT` statement with other columns.

To rephrase the SQL error message you provided, you cannot select data and assign a value from one of the retrieved records to a variable. If you want to use the `SELECT` statement as-is, you must remove all other columns and only select the variable.

For example this is a valid `SELECT` that assign values to a variable:

```sql
SELECT @Var1 = ColumnA,
    @Var2 = ColumnB,
    @Var3 = ColumnC
FROM MyTable;
-- Valid! Each column is assigned to a variable.
```

However, the following is invalid:

```sql
SELECT @Var1 = ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    ColumnC
FROM MyTable;
-- Invalid. Not all columns are assigned to a variable.
```

If you wish to assign a value to a variable using a case expression and then combine the variable's value with a `SELECT` from the same table, you must first run a query that assigns the value to the variable. Then you can query the table and include the variable to the list of columns you wish to select.

```sql
DECLARE @MyVar INT = 0;

-- Set the value of your variable using CASE
SET @MyVar = (
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN <condition> THEN @MyVar + 1
        WHEN <condition> THEN @MyVar + 1
        ELSE @MyVar + 3
        END
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE <condition>)

-- Select the desired columns from your table and append the variable to the end of your column list.
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, @MyVar AS [VariableColumn]
FROM MyTable
WHERE <condition>

-- Note: replace "<condition>" with suitable conditions based on your target table.
```